# kivy+gspread crashes while trying in an android phone, but works fine in my laptop

Tags: kivy, gspread, oauth2client

I am using gspread and oauth2client in a very simple kivy app, I just want to update one cell in my google sheet. The code works just fine in my PC but when I build the apk file using buildozer and upload it to my android phone it crashes. Is there any conflict between gspread and kivy ???? The code is shown below;

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('cl_sec.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open('project2').sheet1

class bxlayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(bxlayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        btn1 = Button(text='ON')
        btn1.bind(on_press=self.clk1)
        self.add_widget(btn1)
        btn2 = Button(text='OFF')
        btn2.bind(on_press=self.clk2)
        self.add_widget(btn2)

    def clk1(self, obj):
        self.background_color = [0,0,1,1]
        sheet.update_cell(2,1, '1')
        self.background_color = [1,1,1,1]

    def clk2(self, obj):
        self.background_color = [0,0,1,1]
        sheet.update_cell(2,1, '0')
        self.background_color = [1,1,1,1]

class appfile(App):
    def build(self):
        ml = bxlayout()
        return ml

if __name__ == "__main__":
    appfile().run()
```

Comment: Can you upload kivy log? I think you forgot to include `gspread` to buildozer's requirements in .spec file

Answer (score 0):

Without `logcat` any question like this pretty much tells **nothing** about the problem because:

- the code obviously works (laptop)
- the packaging apparently too (you can install and launch the app)

so as Eugene suggested, the problem is most likely with you not including the package either in the `buildozer`'s `.spec` file - the important part looks like this:

```
requirements = kivy
```

and for you to use a third-party library you *have to* mention its name in that particular line:

```
requirements = kivy,gspread
```

or with similar `python-for-android` console switch.

Depending on if it's pure-python or C-extension it will or will not throw an error during packaging now. If it's an extension, you need to write a [recipe](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/) for it.